# How to Validate a Character Compatible with MacRoman

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics, mac-roman

Is there a simple way (a function, a method...) of validating a character that a user types to see if it's compatible with Mac OS Roman?  I've read a few dozen topics to find out why an iOS application crashes in reference to **CGContextShowTextAtPoint**.  I guess an application can crash if it tries to draw on an image a string (i.e. ©) containing a character that is not included in the Mac OS Roman set.  There are 256 characters in this set.  I wonder if there's a better way other than matching the selected character one by one with those 256 characters?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might give https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html a closer read.

You can draw any encoding using  `CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint` instead of `CContextShowTextAtPoint` so you can tell it what the encoding is. If the user types it then you'll be getting the string as an NSString which is a Unicode string underneath.  Probably the easiest is going to be to get the utf8 encoding of that user entered string via `NSString`'s `UTF8String` method.

If you really want to stick with the very limited MacRoman for some reason, then use `NSString`'s `cStringUsingEncoding:` passing in `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` to get a MacRoman string.  Read the documentation on this in `NSString` though.  Will return null if the user string can't be encoded in MacRoman losslessly. As it discusses you can use `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` and `canBeConvertedToEncoding:` to check.  Read the cautions in the Discussion for `cStringUsingEncoding:` about about lifecycle of the returned strings though.  `getCString:maxLength:encoding:` might end up being a better choice for you.  All discussed in the [class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for `NSString`.

Comment: I'll take a look at CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer the question but this answer may be a solution to your problem.

If you have an `NSString`, instead of using `CGContextShowTextAtPoint`, you can do:

```
[someStr drawAtPoint:somePoint withFont:someFont];
```

where `someStr` is an `NSString` containing any Unicode characters a user can type, `somePoint` is a `CGPoint`, and `someFont` is the `UIFont` to use to render the text.